# Splitting python list into two lists with conditions

Tags: python

I want to split a list into two groups but I want to make a condition that tom can't be in the same group as jill and barry can't be in the same group as cate and tim can't be in the same group as jody.

I have the following code - but how can I add that condition in?

```
import random
ppl = ['tom','jill', 'barry', 'cate', 'tim', 'jody', 'john']

random.shuffle(ppl)

team_a = ppl[:3]
team_b = ppl[3:]
```

Comment: For this specific list, you can divide it into the even-index values and the odd-index values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trial and error approach, generating random shuffles in a loop and exiting only when neither team has a conflict:

```
import random

people    = ['tom','jill', 'barry', 'cate', 'tim', 'jody', 'john']
exclusive = [('tom','jill'),('barry','cate'),('tim','jody')]

while True:
    random.shuffle(people)
    team_a = people[:3]
    team_b = people[3:]
    if any(map(set(team_a).issuperset,exclusive)):
        continue
    if any(map(set(team_b).issuperset,exclusive)):
        continue
    break

print(team_a)
print(team_b)

['tom', 'jody', 'cate']
['tim', 'jill', 'john', 'barry']
```

For your specific example, since there are only two teams, each exclusive names pair will be split between the two teams.  The only randomness is on which side each name goes.  The final name ('john') will always go in the larger team (team_b).

So you can do this without trial and error by generating random side indexes for the exclusions and assembling the teams with the left and right selections:

```
import random

people    = ['tom','jill', 'barry', 'cate', 'tim', 'jody', 'john']
exclusive = [('tom','jill'),('barry','cate'),('tim','jody')]

exSide = random.choices([0,1],k=len(exclusive))
team_a = [x[i] for x,i in zip(exclusive,exSide)]
team_b = [x[1-i] for x,i in zip(exclusive,exSide)] + ['john']

print(team_a)
print(team_b)
                    
['jill', 'cate', 'tim']
['tom', 'barry', 'jody', 'john']
```